# Passing a program a file for it to read

Tags: c++, stdin

I'm needing to run a program and pass a file into it. It works when writing

```
./my_program input.txt
```

I need it to run while using this format

```
./my_program < input.txt
```

but it throws a segmentation fault.

this isn't my exact code, but it's the idea's that I think are most important.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char *input;
    input = new char[1000];
    if (f == NULL) {
        std::cout << "file not found" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "found file" << std::endl;
    }
    fread(input, 1000, 1, f);
    //...do stuff with it...//
    return 0;
}
```

so basically, how do I get around the '<' throwing a segmentation fault, when it works fine the other way?

Comment: It's not the '<' that throws a segmentation fault. It's the `argv[1]`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes so use argv[2]? without the '<' argv[1] doesn't throw it.

Comment: Running `./my_program < input.txt` runs the program with no arguments (`argv[1]` is `NULL`). Standard input is redirected to read from input.txt.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on `argv[1]` being `NULL`. You should check `argc`. That's what it's for.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst `argv` is guaranteed to be a null-terminated array, so when `argc = 1`, `argv[1]` is `NULL`. It's not wrong to rely on it since it's documented and required behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to think about files. Just write your code as if user typed contents of the input.txt file.

'<' is redirecting contents of specyfied file to your stdin.

Hope this explains more:
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial

Comment: so, using    std::cin    will work the same, the '<' redirects input so that it isn't from keyboard is what i'm getting? yes, it all makes sense now, and works. thank you.